# why do docker compose up --scale set instance to 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a public docker compose plugin to run docker compose job on service machine.
I see this line of code

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p buildkite18e15a6103824eb89c747d49151c7eea up --scale build-premade=0 build-premade
```

What is the purpose of running `--scale build-premade=0`? I get an error when I try to run this locally. ([docker-compose up doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/) grep for --scale)

`no container found for project "{project_name}": not found`.

Anyone seen this before or knows how to get around this? I am guessing there is a docker setting or config somewhere?

reference to GH Issue - https://github.com/buildkite-plugins/docker-compose-buildkite-plugin/issues/322

Comment: this doesnt look like a valid compose command in the first place. `up` has no scale flag. Its also rather odd that you call `run_docker_compose` what is this?

Comment: `run_docker_compose` is a just a bash function that translate to 
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p {project_name}`

https://github.com/buildkite-plugins/docker-compose-buildkite-plugin/blob/1dccf2935514285ef95910372feeb9b05a6995e7/lib/shared.bash#L175

Comment: I will link the doc to scale flag https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/

--scale  Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the scale setting in the Compose file if present.